# How to add new filed by type data to existing documents Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, timestamp

I am trying to add field(key) existing document all records. And i wanna; when new record saved, automaticly save to current date this field;

Now my one document instance of studen
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4f83ed9bcba9560ea474465d"),
  "name" : "",
  "lastname" : "",
  "number" : "",
   .....
}

I want to this;

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4f83ed9bcba9560ea474465d"),
  "name" : "",
  "lastname" : ""
  "Date" :  currentTime()
}

When new record saved to document automaticly save current time to documents. 
I dont wanna do this from client side,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to make sure I am understanding correctly, are you looking to update every document in your collection with a new "Date" field, or are you just looking to add the current date to new documents as they are inserted?

Given a collection (truncated for brevity) like the following:

```
> db.students.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Joe" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Jane" }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Sam" }
>
```

A Date may be added to every document in the collection in a single update statement like so:

```
> db.students.update({}, {$set:{"Date": new Date()}}, false, true)
> db.students.find()
{ "Date" : ISODate("2012-04-10T15:06:34.608Z"), "_id" : 1, "name" : "Joe" }
{ "Date" : ISODate("2012-04-10T15:06:34.608Z"), "_id" : 2, "name" : "Jane" }
{ "Date" : ISODate("2012-04-10T15:06:34.608Z"), "_id" : 3, "name" : "Sam" }
>
```

The false and true values passed to the update function indicate upsert=false and multi=true.  More information on this may be found in the Mongo documentation on the update() function:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29

To add a new Date object to new documents as they are added to the collection, simply create a new Date object when the documents are saved:

```
> db.students.save({ "_id" : 4, "name" : "Chris", "Date":new Date()})
> db.students.find()
{ "Date" : ISODate("2012-04-10T15:06:34.608Z"), "_id" : 1, "name" : "Joe" }
{ "Date" : ISODate("2012-04-10T15:06:34.608Z"), "_id" : 2, "name" : "Jane" }
{ "Date" : ISODate("2012-04-10T15:06:34.608Z"), "_id" : 3, "name" : "Sam" }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "Chris", "Date" : ISODate("2012-04-10T15:12:03.161Z") }
>
```

When a Date object is created in Java Script, with no values passed into the constructor, it will create a date object with the current UTC (universal, or GMT) time.  More information on the Java Script Date object may be found here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Different languages handle dates differently, so depending on which language your application is written in, you will have to check that language's documentation on how it implements a date object.

Hopefully this will get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks your answer. I am newbie at MongoDb. I want to this,
I want to this,
> db.students.save({ "_id" : 4, "name" : "Chris"})
> db.students.find()
{ "Date" : ISODate("2012-04-11T09:56:34.608Z"), "_id" : 1, "name" : "Joe" }

it is looks like trigger or default current date for each new record

Comment: Ah.  I think i understand.  "_id" is the only field that will be added automatically by Mongo to new documents.  If you would like a "date" field to be added to new documents, it will have to be done via the application.